# errors running R script on Clusters

Tags: r, cluster-computing

I'm running an R script using `foreach()` and `%dopar%` on clusters. Without changing anything in my code, the execution of my program is interrupted every time returning 3 different errors:

  1.

```
     Error in unserialize(socklist[[n]]) : error reading from connection
        Calls: %dopar% ... recvOneData -> recvOneData.SOCKcluster -> unserialize
        Execution halted
```

2. ```
       Error in { : 
         task 1 failed - "unable to load shared object '/cluster/apps/r/3.5.1_openblas/x86_64/lib64/R/library/units/libs/units.so':
         libudunits2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
       Calls: %dopar% -> <Anonymous>
       Execution halted
   ```
  3.

```
    TERM_MEMLIMIT: job killed after reaching LSF memory usage limit.
    Exited with exit code 1
```

In the last scenario, I tried increasing the number of nodes or the used memory in the submission command  `bsub -n 23  -W 20:00 -R "rusage[mem=4072]" "R --vanilla --slave <1.algorithm_function_part0_alternative.R> resultFunPart0Alt.out"`, but still it returns the same error or one of the previous two. I'm using the R version 3.5.1.